# How to connect Magento different instances to a central database in an development environment

Tags: magento

We have Magento community edition in our office. The DB server is separate ; we would like to connect a single Magento DB  to multiple instances on separate machines (within LAN network)
Currently each developer has to get a separate DB on his own machine
Any suggestions?

Comment: Configure them to connect to the same database?

Comment: how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Magento is capable of connecting to a remote database. For each developer to connect to a central database, at least two conditions must be met:

1. Each developer must have a local.xml file properly configured to connect to the central database.
2. Each developer must configure his/her localhost to use the same route for their instance of the Magento site. This route needs to match the value stored in the central database's core_config_data table in the rows for web/unsecure/base_url and web/

Depending on the complexity of your Magento site, there may be more steps you need to take. These are the basic steps for a bare bones, single store-front setup.